# differentiating the inverse function

Tags: calculus

I was given the following problem:

> Let $f(x) = x^3+x$. If $h$ is the inverse function of $f$, then $h'(2)=$

I know that to find the derivative of an inverse function you do this: $$\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}x))}$$
The derivative of $f$ is: $3x^2+1$. But, how do I find the $f^{-1}x$?

Comment: hint:  $f^{-1}(2) = a \implies 2 = f(a)$. For what value of $a$ does $f(a)$ become $2$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: you have $y=f(x)$ $\iff$ $x=h(y)$ and the formula
$$
h'(y)=\frac{1}{f'(x)}.
$$
To find $h'(2)$ all you need is the value $x$ that solves $2=f(x)$, i.e. $2=x^3+x$. It is very easy to guess.

Comment: So to find $f^{-1}(x)$ you make the function equal to the value? For example: $f(x)=3x^2+2x+1$, find $f^{-1}(4)$: You set $4$ equal to $3x^2+2x+1$ and solve?

Comment: @burt That's correct. The solution $x$ to $f(x)=4$ is exactly by definition $x=f^{-1}(4)$. If the inverse function exists, the solution $x$ is unique.

Answer (score 1):

You know that $f(f^{-1}(x)) = x$. Applying the chain rule, you get $f'(f^{-1}(x)) (f^{-1}(x))' = 1$. The expression still equals 1 when evaluated at $x = 2$. Knowing that $f = 2$ when $x = 1$, if $h$ is the inverse of $f$, then $h(2) = 1$. Now you have $f'(1) h'(2) = 1$, so you can solve for $h'(2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Try drawing a graph then flipping it. You just need to find the place where $f(x)=2$. Try a few numbers for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

The inverse function is obtained by interchanging $x$ and $y$. It is a reflection about line through origin at $45^{\circ}$to either axis. This also means 
$$ h'(x)=\dfrac{1}{f'(x)}$$
The point $(1,2)$ reflects to $(2,1)$

So you need  to find slope of $f(x) = f'[x)= (3x^2+1)$ at $x=1\, (=4) $and find out its reciprocal $(=\dfrac14 ).$